# How can I solve CSS transition syntax error?

Tags: css, css-transitions, digital-ocean

I wanted to add custom CSS code to our Node JS application in GitHub. I opened the CSS file and pasted the code to the very buttom. The Code that I've got is from Getsitecontrol.com - the code should allow me to show a widget bar at the top of the header, instead covering it.

It seems that Digital Ocean can't deploy, because the word "transition" causes an error. Do you know an alternative word that I can use or why this error can appear?

```css
body {
    transition: padding-top .35s ease-in-out;
    }

    body.getsitecontrol-71519-open {
      padding-top: 176px; // mobile bar height
    }

    @media (min-width: 960px) {
      body.getsitecontrol-71519-open {
        padding-top: 88px; // desktop bar height
      }
    }
```

[Build Logs - Digital Ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEjIS.png)
[Build Error: Non Zero Exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dv2W.png)

Comment: this error is in browser only ?  you can use a parse CSS https://github.com/reworkcss/css

Comment: Please post the error message as well. Otherwise it's guesswork. Instead of `transicion` it is `transition`. Maybe a typo somewhere?

Comment: This problem seems to be on Digital Ocean's end as far as I can tell. Can you not build this application locally?

Comment: @BenjaminKröni what do the logs show? Any more hints why it is failing? (The big dark-blue "View Logs" button)